# DIV with overflow:auto and a 100% wide table

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, html-table

I hope someone might be able to help me here. I've tried to simplify my example as best I can.

I have an absolutely positioned DIV, which for this example I've made fill the browser window. This div has the overflow:auto attribute to provide scroll bars when the content is too big for the DIV to display.

Within the DIV I have a table to present some data, and it's width is 100%.

When the content becomes too large vertically, I expect the vertical scroll bar to appear and the table to shrink horizontally slightly to accommodate the scroll bar. However in IE7 what happens is the horizontal scroll bar also appears, despite there still being enough space horizontally for all the content in the div.

This is IE specific - firefox works perfectly.

Full source below. Any help greatly appreciated.

Tony

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Table sizing bug?</title>
    <style>
        #maxsize
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            border: 5px solid silver;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="maxsize">
        <p>This will be fine until such time as the vertical size forces a
           vertical scroll bar. At this point I'd expect the table to re-size
           to now take into account of the new vertical scroll bar. Instead,
           IE7 keeps the table the full size and introduces a horizontal
           scroll bar.
        </p>
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>E</td>
                <td>F</td>
                <td>G</td>
                <td>H</td>
                <td>I</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>K</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>N</td>
                <td>O</td>
                <td>P</td>
                <td>Q</td>
                <td>R</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        <p>Resize the browser window vertically so this content doesn't
           fit any more</p>
        <p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**added 03/16/10...** thought it might be interesting to point out that GWT's source code points to this question in a comment... http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#MTQ26449crI/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.java&q=%22hack%20to%20account%20for%20the%22%20scrollpanel&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=48

Answer (score 34):

I had a problem with excessive horizonal bar in IE7. I've used D Carter's solution slighty changed

```
<div style="zoom: 1; overflow: auto;">
   <div id="myDiv" style="zoom: 1;">
      <table style="width: 100%"...
      ...
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

To work in IE browser lesser than 7 you need add:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><style> #myDiv { overflow: auto; } </style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: hey, GWT uses this answer and points to it in their source code. :) http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#MTQ26449crI/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.java&q=%22hack%20to%20account%20for%20the%22%20scrollpanel&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=48

Answer (score 9):

Eran Galperin's solution fails to account for the fact that simply turning off horizontal scrolling will still allow the table to underlap the vertical scrollbar. I assume this is because IE is calculating the meaning of "100%" before deciding that it needs a vertical scrollbar, then failing to re-adjust for the remaining horizontal space available.

cetnar's solution above nails it, though:

```
<div style="zoom: 1; overflow: auto;">
   <div id="myDiv" style="zoom: 1;">
      <table style="width: 100%">
      ...
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works properly on IE6 and 7 in my tests. From what I can tell, the "" hack doesn't appear to actually be necessary on IE6.

Comment: To clarify for anyone with the misfortune to be looking into this in 2012 (or later!):

The key is having your 100% width table wrapped in an element with hasLayout (eg, a #myDiv in Joel's example, a div with zoom:1 to trigger hasLayout) INSIDE of the scrolling element with overflow:auto.

This causes IE to reflow the width of the table AFTER taking into account the width of the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
overflow: auto;
```

to:

```
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:auto;
```

Comment: This method suppresses horizontal scrollbars, but it does not redraw the width of the inner table. So when vertical scrollbars are shown, the edge of the inner table is cut off. This may or may not be acceptable in your layout.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, this one plagued me for a LONG time.  I have made far too many designs that have extra padding on the right, allowing for IEs complete disregard for their own scrollbar.

The answer is:  nest two divs, give them both hasLayout, set the inner one to overflow.

```
<!-- zoom: 1 is a proprietary IE property.  It doesn't really do anything here, except give hasLayout -->

<div style="zoom: 1;">
   <div style="zoom: 1; overflow: auto">
      <table style="width: 100%"...
      ...
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Go there to read more about having layout

Comment: I don't think it matters which div has the overflow set.

Comment: @Chad: Could you please provide a fiddle that shows that this does work with overflow set on the inner div. Because that's what I need whereas I can only get it to work the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This is [reported fixed in GWT trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=6354).

Answer (score 1):

If it's the body tag that insists on having the horizontal scroll (I guess because I have child elements set to 100%) you can add this to your CSS to fix the problem in IE7 (or 8 compatibility mode):

```
html{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should fix your problem, as long as you are not apposed to condition statements.  [Fixing IE overflow](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/11/fixing-the-ie-overflow-vertical-scrollbar-bug.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a quirk of IE. There's no way using pure XHTML and CSS to get it to work the same as Firefox.

You could do it using JavaScript to detect the size of the window and set the width of the table dynamically. I can add more detail on that if you really wanted to go that route.