# Body Margin:0, Div Width:100% problem in FF and Chrome, fine in IE

Tags: css, html, width, margin

I'm starting to pull my hair out of my head...

I have the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body { margin:0 auto; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; width: 100%;">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works in IE producing a nice div, 100% width, no H scrollbar...

Now in Chrome and FF, it is 1px wider than the window, causing an H scrollbar...

Why is that? What SHOULD I be using instead?

Thanks a lot!
Albert

EDIT:

I added div { margin: 0; } to the head and removed the width: 100% and it worked, thanks.

Comment: IE is just majorly flawed with the box model. it dose a lot of sizing things wrong. It just happens you tried IE first and think that other broswer are broken. You should also use external CSS. You can set the scroll bar to of via "overflow:hidden"

Comment: I didn't say its a bug in FF and Chrome, I'm just saying I'm having a problem with it. I do use external CSS, this is in a large project and just created this file as a simple example of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `border` is sitting outside of the `width`, so you get `100% + 2px`. Just drop the `width` property – a div is per default 100% wide.

Answer (score 1):

As scavenger already pointed out. The margin of the div ist the problem. Reset everything with this command:

```
<style>
  * { margin:0; }
</style>
```

For more information I recommend you to read [this article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) by Eric Meyer about reseting the CSS in all browsers to the same default values.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to disable the div's margin.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `width:100%` by `margin:0px`

Answer (score 0):

I still had issues with this, in the end, I added a style="zoom: 1;" to the divs

```
<div style="zoom: 1;">
    <div style="zoom: 1;">
        <table style="width: 100%"...
        ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DIV with overflow:auto and a 100% wide table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139000/div-with-overflowauto-and-a-100-wide-table-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and this way works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    body { margin:0 auto; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; width: 100%;">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```