# IE8 horizontal scrollbar problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have an IE8 buggy horizontal scrollbar problem,
similar to this:

[DIV with overflow:auto and a 100% wide table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139000/div-with-overflowauto-and-a-100-wide-table-problem)

(unfortunately the solution suggested there (with zoom=1) does not work here,
or I don't know how to apply)

the horizontal scrollbar should not appear
(it does not appear in FF or Chrome
but it appears in IE8)

the sample code, with CSS tables:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 19em;">
            <div style="width: 30em; height: 30em; background-color: red;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the same problem, with absolute positioning:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute;">
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 19em;">
<div style="width: 30em; height: 30em; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the "overflow-x: hidden" solution is not good, because it may hide some content;
padding-right may work, but that's too dirty hack (how many pixels? what happens in other browsers? what if the user magnifies the page?)

Comment: I would like a CSS-only solution (no javascript)

Comment: I posted another question, that generalizes this issue; please check out, and lets go over to there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554137/general-container-ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the display:inline-block; for the div that contains the red box

```
 <div style="display: table;">
<div style="display: table-cell;">
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 19em; display:inline-block;">
        <div style="width: 30em; height: 30em; background-color: red;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree, he mentioned the issue with IE8, so i just try it there, if he needs compatibility with IE7/6,  it might not work, I didn't test the bug there so not really sure.

Comment: this is one of the possible solutions; `float: left` and `position: absolute` are also OK

Comment: thanks for the incoming, with the floated solution did you need to clear the element, didn't you?

Comment: no, I did not have to clear it. there are two little problems with this solution: 1: I can not use `overflow-y: auto`, because it causes horizontal scrollbar in FF and Chrome; 2: in IE8 the vertical scrollbar goes "outside" of the box (in FF and Chrome it is inside; it's also inside in IE8 without this inline-block/float/position:absolute thing)

Answer (score 1):

With your first example, if you move the `width:30em` from the inner most DIV to it's *parent* the horizontal scrollbar no longer appears in IE8 and still functions properly in other browsers:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <div style=" width:30em; height: 19em;overflow-y: scroll;">
            <div style="height: 30em; background-color: red; ">Content goes here.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rev7J/

Comment: The same will work for your second example (the absolute positioned DIVs).

Comment: I did not tell the whole story: I try to make a general container, and the red box is just a sample content in it; so we should not poke with the red box. I posted another question, that generalizes this issue; please check out, and lets go over to there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554137/general-container-ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem

Comment: @slobo, so are you able to mark one of the answers correct that suit your listed question then?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change the overflow value from "scroll" to "auto". Scroll gives both horizontal and vertical bars whether you need them or not. Also IE for some reason requires the innermost box to be slightly smaller than its outer boxes for this to work correctly. Finally that means if you want to change your background do so in an outer Div rather than inside an inner one.

See the solution to your inquiry below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
#redBox  {
    position:relative;
}
#insideBox {
    overflow:auto;
    height: 19em;
    width:30em;
    background-color: red;
}

#innerMost {
    width: 28em;
    height: 30em;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="redBox">
    <div id="insideBox">
        <div id="innerMost">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Following on from your above answer, you don't even have to set a width or height to the #innerMost DIV - just add some padding for styling: http://jsfiddle.net/RnHs2/ Seems to work well cross-browser.

Comment: I did not tell the whole story: I try to make a general container, that is vertically constrained, but can grow horizontally. I posted another question; please check out, and lets go over to there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554137/general-container-ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
 style="max-height:none\9;"
```