# general container - IE8 horizontal scrollbar problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I ran into the following problem:
how to make a general container (HTML + CSS; no javascript)
that is contrained vertically (it has a fixed outer height), so it may have a vertical scrollbar
but that can grow horizontally (as needed by the content of the container), so it never has a horizontal scrollbar

it has to work in IE8, FF, Chrome (no IE7 or earlier)

the solution semms to be be trivial at first
but I can not get rid of the horizontal scrollbar in IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="display: table;" class="container-div-1">
    <div style="display: table-cell;" class="container-div-2">
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 19em;" class="container-div-3">
            <div style="width: 30em; height: 30em; background-color: red;" class="example-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in this example, we need a 19em high container, that can grow horizontally, as needed by the content (in this case, the "example-cotent" div)
please don't suggest to modify the "example-content" div, as it is just a sample content (any content could be there)

this problem is the generalization of this issue:
[IE8 horizontal scrollbar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546454/ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem)

Comment: important: the container should not expand horizontally, just as much as needed by the content (thats why the outer CSS-table is there)

Comment: I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558592/general-container-ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem-revisited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating will probably get the result you're looking for. Check out my example here:
http://jsbin.com/ivegi4/4/edit

I took away the containing divs, as I didn't think they were necessary, but I wouldn't see a problem adding them back in if you absolutely needed them.

Comment: nice, it really works... but one more thing: if I want `overflow-y: auto` instead of `overflow-y: scroll`, FF and Chrome shows the horizontal scrollbar (IE8 does not)! how can I get rid of this horizontal scrollbar? http://jsfiddle.net/slobo/EY8kj/5/

Comment: I noticed something about this solution: in IE8 the vertical scrollbar goes outside of the box (this applies to the `position: absolute` and the `display: inline-block` solutions also)

Comment: The scroll bar going outside the box is what prevents the horizontal scroll bar from showing up. If it went inside, the width of the content would be clipped and a horizontal scroll bar would show up.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: absolute` on the `container-div-3` div. This will cause the div to shrink-wrap whatever is inside, and works fine in IE8.

Comment: I added 'position: absolute' on the container-div-2 div. Nothing changed. Have I missed something??

Comment: Ooops, sorry, that should be 3 not 2! Try it now. :)

Comment: nice, it really works... but one more thing: if I want `overflow-y: auto` instead of `overflow-y: scroll`, FF and Chrome shows the horizontal scrollbar (IE8 does not)! how can I get rid of this horizontal scrollbar? http://jsfiddle.net/slobo/EY8kj/7/