# general container - CSS horizontal scrollbar problem

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

this is a follow-up to this issue:
[general container - IE8 horizontal scrollbar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554137/general-container-ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem)

I would like to create a `float:left` (or 'position: absolute' - the same problem) container
that is constrained vertically (it has a fixed outer height) - so it may have a vertical scrollbar;
but that can grow horizontally (as needed by the content of the container), so it never has a horizontal scrollbar

it has to work in IE8, FF, Chrome (no IE7 or earlier)

the solution seems to be trivial
but I can not get rid of the horizontal scrollbar in FF or Chrome (IE8 is OK):

```
<div style="float: left; height: 20em; overflow-y: auto;" class="container-div">
    <div style="width: 30em; height: 30em; background-color: red;" class="example-content"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slobo/pydsZ/

in this example, we need a 20em high container, that can grow horizontally, as needed by the content (in this case, the "example-content" div)
please don't suggest to modify the "example-content" div, as it is just a sample content (any content could be there)

modifying `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-y: scroll` solves the problem; but I would like to keep `overflow-y: auto`

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the horizontal scrollbar:

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

Comment: this solution would hide some content, wouldn't it? I do not want to hide any content, of course

Comment: I checked it: this solution hides some content, so this is not an acceptable solution

Answer (score 0):

set floater's width to some fixed value to fix it, if it doesn't work set to 100%

Comment: as I stated in my question, the container should grow horizontally, as needed by the content (so no fixed or 100% width)