# Remove horizontal scrolling in IE 8-10 using overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On firefox, chrome and safari, the following css sets the width of the document to the screen size, and clips anything outside of it.

```
body, html {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
```

This allows you to create background elements larger than the width of the documents and have them not change the final size of the document.

Unfortunately IE doesn't seem to allow this approach (I've tested IE 8-10), and even though it supports overflow-x and wont show a scroll-bar, you can still scroll horizontally by highlighting content and dragging to the right.

Is there anyway to get this to work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support overflow element in css

you have to use max-height property for that element.

Comment: I'm looking to restrict the width, not the height, so max-height doesn't apply to this question. Also IE does support overflow and overflow-x according to their documentation, so I dont know where you're getting that it isn't supported.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530826(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546454/ie8-horizontal-scrollbar-problem

Comment: restriction of width is very simple,
you have to apply just mac-width:100%.

Comment: using width:100% already applies the same rules as max-width:100% so this wont work either. (Also I've tried it just in case IE is weird, but it really doesn't work)